# Create dictionary with new keys from old dictionary keys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Using LINQ, I want to create a new dictionary with keys that are a property of an old dictionary's keys, but with the same values as in the old dictionary.

Example:

```
class Shape
{
    int position;
}

Shape shape = new Shape();

Dictionary<Shape, string> shapes = new Dictionary<Shape, string>(){ {shape , "circle"} };

//attempt 1:
Dictionary<int, string> shapePositions = shapes
                                          .GroupBy(x=> x.Key.Position))
                                          .ToDictionary( x => shapes.Key, **x=> x.Value** );
```

I expected to be able to use the above code to convert an old `Dictionary<Shape, string>` to a new `Dictionary<int, string>`.

So the values of both are equal but the keys of the new `Keys` are a property of the olds `Keys` such that the following returns true

```
shapes.Key.Position == shapes.Key
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Because the result of `GroupBy` is not a dictionary but in your case an `IEnumerable<IGrouping>`

Comment: So you want `shapes.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.Position, x=> x.Value );`? Or do you actually want to do some kind of aggregation on Position and therefore tried something with GroupBy?

Comment: yes something like that. Though I think I ended up using GroupBy too much simplify some of my LINQ statements with what you have written. Thanks @Ralf :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a `GroupBy` - you get a collection of groups, that have a `Key` property (the grouped value) and another enumerable of the items within that group.

So at that point the "Items" in the group are a collection of key-value pairs, with a `Key` property that has the value of `position` shared by all of these items. Since it's not clear what the "value" in the new dictionary should be, it's hard to give a general example, but if you *assume* that each group only has one item, then you could take the value from the first item:

```
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Value);
```

But consider what the output should be if you have multiple shapes with the exact same position (meaning you'll have *two* strings in the collection of values)